# How to list down the values in a name range using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have a name range *Month* and it has value from (jan,...., dec) . I want to list them using VBA.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please provide what you have so far and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have listed them as `Month` like below,

[image]

Use the below code to loop through the named range `Month` and print the output in `Column B`,

```
Sub namedRange()
Dim RangeArray() As Variant, i As Integer
RangeArray = Range("Month")
For i = 1 To 12
    Cells(i, 2) = RangeArray(i, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```